# What am I doing wrong here with my PIVOT function?

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I'm pretty new to SQL and am trying to get the query to work below using the `PIVOT()` function. Below is what I've tried based on what I've read online. Can someone help me out here?

---

Current SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) *
FROM
(SELECT CVE, SERV_WS_RATING, RATING
FROM dummyTable
) AS sourceTable PIVOT([RATING] FOR [SERV_WS_RATING] IN ([SERVER],[WORKSTATION])) AS pivotTable
```

Current Output:

| CVE | Server/Workstation Rating | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CVE-1999-0001 | Server | P1 |
| CVE-1999-0001 | Workstation | P1 |
| CVE-1999-0002 | Server | P3 |
| CVE-1999-0002 | Workstation | P3 |
| CVE-1999-0003 | Server | P5 |
| CVE-1999-0003 | Workstation | P5 |

Desired Output:

| CVE | Server Rating | Workstation Rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CVE-1999-0001 | P1 | P1 |
| CVE-1999-0002 | P3 | P3 |
| CVE-1999-0003 | P5 | P5 |

Comment: seems you missed aggregation(MIN or MAX) within the nested part after PIVOT clause [such as](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=65bb87ca9cad1dc3e841c940ebcb0634) presuming the input as in the linked demonstartion, else please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is conditional aggregation

```
select CVE, 
       max(case when SERV_WS_RATING='Server' then RATING else null end) [Server Rating],
       max(case when SERV_WS_RATING='Workstation' then RATING else null end) [Workstation Rating]       
from dummyTable
group by CVE
order by CVE;
```